# Creating a Bartik sub-theme in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have been playing with Drupal 8. At the moment I want to have an image as the header background in Bartik. For this I created a subtheme called "freex" in the following way:

Create folder freex in /themes/custom/

Create freex.info.yml in /themes/custom/freex/ containing:

```
name: Freex
description: Basis thema voor verenigingen
type: theme
core: 8.x
base theme: bartik

libraries:
  - freex/global-styling
```

Create file freex.libraries.yml in /themes/custom/freex/ containing:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Create file in /themes/custom/freex/css/ called style.css containing:

```
#header {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Just to see of it works... It doesn't, the header does not change background color. Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: did you active this theme from Appearance

Comment: Is your custom theme displayed under Appearance? Did you activate this theme? Does the style.css file gets included? Please give some more info

Comment: Yes, the css file is included, I find it back in:

files/css/css_ety5xdAt69LTpeH6p9fbVbET2KclBgUgZCeet9COWtE.css?o4sf9o

When I do: View source, so the question becomes, why does my entry:

#header{background-color:yellow;}

Not make the header background yellow?

Also, how does one add a newline in a comment so that it stays readable here?

Comment: You can turn off the color module! Or manipulate it to get the colors you want.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the page cache: Configuration Menu -> Development -> Performance
Uncheck the checkboxes : Aggregate Css files, aggregate javascript files.
If you do this, when you see page source, you see your file name style.css - not the generated css file name, as you write. At the top of the performance page, click to clear all cache. And after that, see your page.

Answer (score 0):

The Bartik theme includes colors.css last (I think it's auto-generated from the theme settings) so the subtheme colours are overriden by the later color module colours.

Add "!important" to your CSS color settings, so they won't be overridden. For example:

```
#header {
  background-color: #CDBE79 !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CDBE79 0%, #CDBE79 100%) !important;
}
```